# Postfix ++ Operator Not Behaving As Expected Inside While Condition

Tags: c, while-loop, increment, post-increment, postfix-operator

I've written a simple solution for the *Brian Kernighan*'s "**The C Programming Language**" ***Exercise 1-19***, that which reverses a character string. The `reverse(char[])` function is as below and everything is fine with it;

```
void reverse(char src[])
{   
    int len = 0;
    while( src[len] != '\0')
        len++;

    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = src[i];
        src[i] = src[len - 1 - i];
        src[len - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

However, if I use the **postfix increment (++) operator** inside the while loop, the function fails;

```
void reverse(char src[])
{   
    int len = 0;
    while( src[len++] != '\0')      // this fails
        ;

    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = src[i];
        src[i] = src[len - 1 - i];
        src[len - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
```

The only difference is, instead of incrementing the variable *len* inside the while loop, I used a postfix ++ operator that which the behaviour expectation should be as, "Use the old value for conditional check, after finished increment it".

Why it is not working as expected, where am I doing wrong? I'm compiling it under Windows 10 Mingw/gcc compiler. Here is the whole test code;

## Test Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_NUM     5
#define STR_SIZE    20

void reverse(char[]);   // declaration

int main()
{   
    char str[STR_NUM][STR_SIZE] =
    {
        { "A"     },
        { "AB"    },
        { "ABC"   },
        { "ABCD"  },
        { "ABCDE" }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < STR_NUM; i++)
        reverse(str[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < STR_NUM; i++)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);

    return 0;
}

// this is working
void reverse(char src[])
{   
    int len = 0;
    while( src[len] != '\0')
        len++;

    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = src[i];
        src[i] = src[len - 1 - i];
        src[len - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}

// this is failing
/*
void reverse(char src[])
{   
    int len = 0;
    while( src[len++] != '\0')      // this fails
        ;

    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
    {
        char temp = src[i];
        src[i] = src[len - 1 - i];
        src[len - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see what `len` ends up as. It's still playing according to the rules, but it gets incremented *even though* you are at the end if your string.

Comment: Rad Lexus is right. For an empty string, the code executes `while (src[len++] != '\0');` which isn't true because `src[0] == '\0'`. After that, `len` will be 1 because of `len++`. Your string with a length of 0 will be considered to have a length of 1.

Comment: start with `len == -1` and use `while(src[++len])`.

Comment: @EOF Yes I've tried that for prefix increment operator with -1 and that's working. Now I've got it, because that I use the postfix operator inside the conditional expression, even if the conditional is false, it will increment the variable thus the variable's value will be always one ahead of what it actually should be. Thanks for useful comment.

Comment: @RadLexus has the best solution - `use a debugger` (that's pretty good advice for every problem posted on SO btw)

Comment: @KevinDTimm Well actually, I've already debugged the code on VS and yes it helps to see the state of the variable. However in this special case, because that the variable in the conditional expression, it is hard to  see what happens before and after in one line of code. Anyways, thank you all for your useful comments which helped to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The postfix increment operator returns the original value and increments by one.

```
while( src[len] != '\0')
    len++;
```

In the working version, the while loop will terminate when `src[len]` is a `\0`. When the while loop test condition fails the statement inside the loop does not execute. After the loop `len` contains a value such that `src[len] == '\0'`.

```
while (src[len++] != '\0');
```

In your modified version, when the final test is preformed `len` will be incremented one additional time. After the loop `len` contains a value such that `src[len]` is one past the end of the array.

However the `for` loop assumes that `len` is the string length, so you have an off-by-one error.